# How to replice Entity Framework FirstOrDefaultAsync

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await, asp.net-identity

When working with ASP.NET identity and customizing **UserStore** to my own set of database tables using **entity framework** like this

```
public Task<MyUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
{
   var context = new CompanyDbContext();

   Task<MyUser> task = context.MyUsers.Where(u => u.UserName == userName)
                                      .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

   return task;
}
```

and calling it like this works fine:

```
MyUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
```

Now, I would like to replace it with a hard coded list of users like below:

```
public Task<MyUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
{
   var myusers = new List<MyUser> 
   { 
       new MyUser() { Id="1", UserName = "tom", Password = "secret" },
       new MyUser() { Id="2", UserName = "mary", Password = "supersecret" }
   };

   Task<MyUser> task = new Task<MyUser>(() => myusers.SingleOrDefault(
                                                  u => u.UserName == userName));

   return task;
}
```

But this does not work as it hangs at this line

```
MyUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
public Task<MyUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
{
   var myusers = new List<MyUser> 
   { 
       new MyUser() { Id="1", UserName = "tom", Password = "secret" },
       new MyUser() { Id="2", UserName = "mary", Password = "supersecret" }
   };

   var task = Task.FromResult(myusers.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName));

   return task;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You created the `Task`, but never started it, so it never runs, so waiting on it means waiting forever.

You could add a call to `Start` after creating the task, but the preferable option when creating a task that you want to be run right away is to simply use `Task.Run` (or `Task.Factory.StartNew` if you're using .NET 4.0).

On top of *that*, your code doesn't even really need to be run in a background thread.  It will complete fast enough that you can simply execute it synchronously.  You can just use `Task.FromResult` to compute the result and wrap it in an already completed task.

Comment: How fast it runs is immaterial in the op's case. Since this is ASP.NET, they should not use `Task.Run` (or `StartNew` (or `Start`)).

Comment: @StephenCleary You're suggesting that were this to actually be a long running operation that it should block synchronously, despite being an async method?  That doesn't sound right.  It seems that this is just a mock up of something that will actually be asynchronous for the sake of testing.

Comment: No; if this is a long-running production operation, I'm saying it should block synchronously in a synchronous method (because you don't want to offload on ASP.NET). If you're testing/mocking, then I'd assume it's not long-running, and `Task.FromResult` would be best. I can't envision a realistic scenario where you'd have a long-running test stub.

Comment: @StephenCleary Neither can I, which is why the proposed solution that my answer arrives at is to use `FromResult` to wrap a result computed synchronously.